# cannot initailaize Microsoft.PointOfService in activex control

Tags: c#, javascript, activex

I am using Microsoft.PointOfService.dll to instantiate explore the printer functionality in a class library. When i am inheriting that class library from a .cs code its working fine. But when i am using that class library to create a cab file to work as an ActiveX control and calling the same method from javascript, it is not instantiating the PosExplorer and giving the exeception as "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer' threw an exception."

I have used the config file and inserted the `<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>`

Do i need any additional things to do while creating setup file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your app.config (It will definitely work on .net 4.0, can you tell me which version are you using?)

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
          <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
        </runtime>
</configuration>
```

If it doesn't work then  you can also try to open the location :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe.config
In this file add the following line

```
<runtime>
<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
```

Comment: I have developed the application in the .net 4.0. Its works fine in the system where i have developed the activex control. but if a client is using the same, after installing the activex control, its giving the same error... Do in need to install "POS for .Net v1.12" in the client system also...?

Comment: I have resolved the issue in my system but in other system it has the issue in initializing the POS..

Comment: Ahhhhh, yes you can try installing it atleast one of the system and revert back in case of success/failure, but it is not recommended approach. Meanwhile I will look for a solution

Comment: Yes, By instaling the "POS for .Net v1.12" it resolved the issue.. Thanks

Comment: If you feel my answer was useful then please accept this answer.